# I am trying to change log4j xml file to log4j propeties file and could someone please verify that i`ve done it right?

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j, testng

I am using log4j properties file in my testNG project. And i have integrated reportPortal in it. Now i want to get rid of DEBUG messages from "com.epam.reportportal" logger in my console which i don`t want to view

I have found on that page that:
ReportPortal' agent logs can be hidded by increasing logging level for the following package:

```
 <logger name="rp">
<level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.epam.reportportal">
<level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

And i changed it to log4j properties:

```
log4j.logger.rp=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.epam.reportportal=ERROR
```

But debug messages from com.epam.reportportal still displayed in console output. Did i make some mistake when was converting log4j xml strings to log4j.properties or what?

My logger file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, reportportal

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8

#Cp1251
#log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=Cp1251
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.reportportal=com.epam.ta.reportportal.log4j.appender.ReportPortalAppender
log4j.appender.reportportal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.reportportal.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p - %m%n

log4j.logger.rp=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.epam.reportportal=ERROR
```

Comment: If you are just comparing what is in the xml vs what's in the properties file, then you'r properties file is correct. If you can post some sample log file, it would help us answer you.

Comment: Check if you have your log4j.properties in a proper place. For example for tests the file is in test resource folder. I have just tested your configuration and it seems to be fine. I only changed report portal appender to a file appender. So my guess is your configuration is not used by log4j. There is some other config in class path that is being used.